# Set volume levels by application in sound indicator applet?

Tags: sound, indicator

Is there any way to set appliactions sound (separately by application) in the new sound indicator applet like in the "sound preferences" window?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it was decided not to include this in the new sound indicator applet. You will have to click on Sound Preferences from the menu to do so.